# How does Index Scan actually work?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have the simple table `foo` with an index on one of its columns, created and filled as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
  c1 integer,
  c2 text
)

CREATE INDEX ON foo(c1);

INSERT INTO foo
  SELECT i, md5(random()::text)
  FROM generate_series(1, 1000000) AS i;
```

Now, I'm trying to understand how `Index Scan` works. I ***first thought*** that each leaf of `btree` indexes contains the pointer to the ***only one page*** of the actual data, values of the indexed column (for doing `Index Only Scan`) and probably something else (I don't what it is). Now, I ran my experiments on the following query:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE c1 < _X_;
```

where `_X_` running from `2` to `255`.

The query

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE c1 < 2;
```

returns this:

```
Index Scan using foo_c1_idx on foo  (cost=0.00..8.38 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=1 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (c1 < 2)
```

And that's clear. We have two random accesses (one to the index leaf, and another one to the actual page of data) and some `CPU` cost as I was explained [there](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117065/how-does-postgresql-compute-the-cost-for-index-scan). Now, by increasing the `_X_` by `1` untill reaching  `255` I got cost increased averagely on `0.02`. But when I setted `_X_` to 256 the cost was increased by 1.02.

Does it have something to do with the fact that `256` is a power of `2`?

Here the plans:

```
Index Scan using foo_c1_idx on foo  (cost=0.00..13.54 rows=239 width=37) (actual time=0.008..0.040 rows=254 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (c1 < 255)
```

and

```
Index Scan using foo_c1_idx on foo  (cost=0.00..14.56 rows=240 width=37) (actual time=0.008..0.044 rows=255 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (c1 < 256)
```

So, it looks like we read an additional page ***sequentially*** to read the row. If so, I'd guess that the leaf contains pointers to more that 1 page that can be read sequentially.

***QUESTION:*** What exactly do leafs of `btree` indexes contain in them? I now think that they contain **indexed column values** and **pointers to some pages** (1 or more).

Comment: The source code and comments might be your best source of information here.

Comment: @CraigRinger So, it's not specified somewhere in the documentation how the leafs actually designed, is it?

Comment: @CraigRinger Did you mean [nodeIndexscan.c](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/executor/nodeIndexscan.c)

Comment: Be awared that cost is the estimation. It is what the planner thinks about how many resources it will take to perform the query. It is calculated using some mathematical model which can be more or less accurate. So looking at cost, you're trying to understand that model, but not how index scan actually works.

Comment: There is a semicolon missing from your table definition.